# how to add custom meta box for woocommerce review?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show some information in woocommerce review edit section and I don't know how to put them in woocommerce review
I tested this code in bottom but it doesn't work

```
function kral_product_review_metabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'kral_product_review',
        'اطلاعات دیدگاه',
        'kral_product_review_fields_metabox',
        'product-reviews',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'kral_product_review_metabox');

function kral_product_review_fields_metabox($post) {

    wp_nonce_field(basename(FILE), 'kral_product_review_nonce');

?>
    <p>
        <label for="kral_product_name">label</label>
        <br />
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="kral_product_name" id="kral_product_name" value="salaaaaaaaaaaaaam" />
    </p>
<?php
}
```

Comment: You want this for the frontend review form or when editing it in the backend?

Comment: for editing in the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong *post type* value as screen value and the wrong context value.

The correct screen name will be `comment` not `product-reviews`

WordPress Documentation says that you can use `side` as context value when adding meta boxes on the comments page but I am not sure why it doesn't work with the `side` value.

Correct `add_meta_box` code will look like this:

```php
add_meta_box(
    'kral_product_review',
    'اطلاعات دیدگاه',
    'kral_product_review_fields_metabox',
    'comment',
    'normal',
);
```